# how to store a for loop in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

```
symbols_list = ["COST","WMT", "GOOGL"]

symbols = []

for ticker in symbols_list:  

    tick = yf.Ticker(ticker)

    history = tick.history(period='max')

    history['Symbol'] = ticker

    symbols.append(history)
```

How should I store values of this for loop into a dataframe?

Comment: You can't "store" a for loop since it is a control structure not data.

Answer (score 1):

The individual data from yf.Ticker should already be a [dataframe](https://algotrading101.com/learn/yfinance-guide/). Hence, your symbol list can be easily [concatenated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) at the end of the loop:

```
df = pd.concat(symbols)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I got the results I want.